# Proof that the function is uniformly continuous and give an attribute...

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Proof that $f: [0, 1] \ni x \mapsto \sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ is
>   uniformly continuous. After, give a concrete number $\delta > 0$ with
>   the following attribute:
>
> For all $x, x_{0} \in [0, 1]$ with $|x - x_{0}| < \delta : |f(x) -
>  f(x_{0})| < 10^{-3}$

I have started with proof that the function is continuous:

Let's say $x = 0$, then $x_{0} < \varepsilon^{2} \Rightarrow  \sqrt{x_{0}} < \varepsilon$

Now we need to show that for $x, x_{0} > 0, |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_{0}}| \leq  \sqrt{|x - x_{0}|}$.

Therefor let be $ x > x_{0}$

$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_{0}}| \leq \sqrt{|x - x_{0}|}$

$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_{0}} \leq \sqrt{x - x_{0}}$

$\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{x - x_{0}} + \sqrt{x_{0}}$

$x \leq x - x_{0} + x_{0} + 2\sqrt{(x - x_{0})x_{0}}$

$x \leq x + 2 \sqrt{(x - x_{0})x_{0}}$

Case $x_{0} > x$ is actually the same procedure.

In the end we get that $\delta = \varepsilon^{2}$ since

$|x - x_{0}| < \varepsilon^{2} \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x_{0}}| \leq \sqrt{|x - x_{0}|} < \varepsilon$

After having shown the continuity of $f$, we see that the interval is closed.
Knowing that $f$ is continuous too, we can say that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I hope it's correct so far?

However I have no idea how to do the second part of this...with $10^{-3}$.

Maybe a good start would be proofing : $\sqrt{x_{0} + d} - \sqrt{x_{0}} \leq \sqrt{d}$ for all $x_{0}, d \geq 0$.
I have already tried that but I didn't come to an end / solution, really frustrating.

Comment: You already found delta in terms of epsilon and you got epsilon = 10^-3

Comment: So I just take this and replace it with epsilon or..?

Comment: Yes that's the answer. That question tests whether you really understood or not , and since you perfectly proved the statement then it shouldn't be hard to the second question ;)